# How to change default date_output_format in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I went through the Snowflake docs and found that the default date_output_format in snowflake is `"YYYY-MM-DD"`.
We can change it to per session as (`alter session set date_output_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY'`).

But I want to change the default value irrespective of the session. So that whenever I open the snowflake and query the date should be in the format `"DD-MON-YYYY"`.

Can anyone please help me, if it's possible to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on needs [DATE_OUTPUT_FORMAT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#date-output-format) could be set up on `ACCOUNT`/`USER` level:

```
ALTER ACCOUNT SET date_output_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY';

ALTER USER <user_name> SET date_output_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY';
```

Related: [Parameter Hierarchy and Types](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#parameter-hierarchy-and-types)